# pytest does not recognize my mocked nested functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a module `scheduler_api.py`, that has a simple create function, that calls nested functions `get_client().create_scheduler`.

```
def create(scheduler : Scheduler):
        try:
            if scheduler is not None:
                scheduler = get_client().create_scheduler(title=scheduler.title, description=scheduler.description)
                return scheduler
        except Exception as ex:
            raise (
                ValueError("Fail to create Scheduler. Exception: %s" % (ex))
        )
```

I have written a simple unit test test_create to test this function. though I have mocked the function `drpCtReactor.utils.reactor_client.get_client`, the pytest still tries to invoke this function and fails. Anything I am missing here?

Unit tests

```
def test_create():
    scheduler_to_create = Scheduler(title = "test_scheduler", description="test scheduler")
    stub_scheduler_created = Scheduler(uuid="1", title="test_scheduler", description="test scheduler")

    with patch("drpCtReactor.utils.reactor_client.get_client") as mock_client:
        mock_client.return_value.create_scheduler.return_value = stub_scheduler_created
        create(scheduler_to_create)
```

Comment: Can you add, at your code, the import of the function `get_client` in the file `scheduler_apy.py`? I think that you have to mock the function in the module `scheduler_apy.py` and not in `drpCtReactor.utils.reactor_client`!

Answer (score 0):

From the Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html):

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up,
> which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

What this means is that you should replace the `target` argument of the `patch` function with `import.path.to.scheduler_api.get_client`, since that is where the function is used.

Since you are using pytest, I would recommend you to define a fixture instead of using mocks, so that you won't have to worry about where functions are used. I would have gotten rid of the need to mock anything by passing `get_client` as an argument to the function (with the `get_client` as a default so you don't have to specify it when using it anywhere else) and defined a fixture that is much easier to define and configure to pass to the function during the tests.

In `scheduler_api.py`:

```py
def create(scheduler : Scheduler, scheduler_creator=get_client().create_scheduler):
    try:
        if scheduler is not None:
            scheduler = get_client().create_scheduler(title=scheduler.title, description=scheduler.description)
            return scheduler
    except Exception as ex:
        raise (
            ValueError("Fail to create Scheduler. Exception: %s" % (ex))
        )
```

and in the unit test:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fake_create_schedule():
    def create_schedule():
        stub_scheduler_created = Scheduler(uuid="1", title="test_scheduler", description="test scheduler")
        return stub_scheduler_created

    return create_schedule


def test_create(fake_create_schedule):
    scheduler_to_create = Scheduler(title = "test_scheduler", description="test scheduler")
    create(scheduler_to_create, scheduler_creator=fake_create_schedule)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more clarity on @Syntaxén answer:

You should replace in your test:

`with patch("drpCtReactor.utils.reactor_client.get_client") as mock_client:`

by

`with patch("scheduler_api.get_client") as mock_client:`

So, the `get_client` you're patching is the one in `scheduler_api.py` AFTER it is already imported.